# Duvida com Notificação e AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-notification, android-alarmmanager

O que preciso é uma dica, ajuda para saber como  implementar um AlarmManager que sempre que chegar uma notificação apareça algo assim

[image]

Na Tela Inicial do celular e fica fazendo um som a cada 5s

para o notificação tenho o seguinte código

```
protected void criarNotificacao(Context context, MensagemAlerta messagesAlerts, Class<?> activity) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notificaction = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            messagesAlerts.getTitle(), System.currentTimeMillis());

    notificaction.sound = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "6");

    notificaction.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

    notificaction.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class), 0);

    notificaction.setLatestEventInfo(this, messagesAlerts.getSubTitle(),
            messagesAlerts.getBody(), p);

    notificaction.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 1000, 1000, 1000 };

    notificationManager.notify(R.string.app_name, notificaction);
}
```

A outra class

```
public class MensagemAlerta {

private CharSequence title;

private CharSequence body;

private CharSequence subTitle;

public MensagemAlerta(CharSequence title, CharSequence body,

                      CharSequence subTitle) {

    this.title = title;

    this.body = body;

    this.subTitle = subTitle;

}

public CharSequence getTitle() {

    return title;

}

public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

    this.title = title;

}

public CharSequence getBody() {

    return body;

}

public void setBody(CharSequence body) {

    this.body = body;

}

public CharSequence getSubTitle() {

    return subTitle;

}

public void setSubTitle(CharSequence subTitle) {

    this.subTitle = subTitle;

}}
```

OBS: chamo essa função de dentro de um Thread

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: preciso implementar uma chamada de AlarmManager com uma tela como a que informei e fique vibrando, tocando um som de 5 em 5s

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, o que você precisa é o seguinte:

Primeiro você precisa criar um `BroadcastReceiver` para seu `AlarmManager` chamar:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AlarmReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Suas implementações (tocar som, vibrar, etc.)
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de adiciona-lo no seu `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver
    android:name="seupackage.AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
```

Depois de criado seu `BroadcastReceiver`, faça seu `AlarmManager` chama-lo (dentro da sua notificação, por exemplo):

```
private void callAlarm() {
    //Definindo o intervalo de 5 segundos
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    //Criando sua PendingIntent com o BroadcastReceiver que você criou
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(),
            0,
            alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    );

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    //Tempo que você quer que seu alarme se repita (em milisegundos)
    final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 5;

    //Definindo o loop do Alarme
    manager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            REPEAT_TIME,
            pendingAlarm
    );
}
```